# I have a question about some concepts and code

Tags: c

We know that for a static variable, the following code is wrong.

```
//this fails: can't call gsl_vector_alloc() before main() starts

static gsl_vector *scratch = gsl_vector_alloc(20);
```

We can solve this by using a macro.

The book says we have to [start at zero and allocate on first use]

```
#define Staticdef(type, var, initialization) \ 
    static type var = 0; \
    if (!(var)) var = (initialization);
```

//usage:

```
Staticdef(gsl_vector*, scratch, gsl_vector_alloc(20));
```

I don't understand:

1. why we have to start on zero.
2. what it means by allocate on first use.
3. why can't I just write:

   ```
   #define Staticdef(type, var, initialization) \
       static type var = (initialization);
   ```
4. "This works as long as we don’t ever expect initialization to be zero (or in pointer-speak, NULL). If it is, it’ll get reinitialized on the next go-round." I don't understand why it'll get REinitialized. [I know static variables can be initialized once and will remember its value even if the frame dies, which will be used to count how many times a function gets called]

I am a new C programmer, so be kind with me if my question seems obvious.
Thank you in advance!

OK, I now fully understand point 1 and point 3 above, for point 2, I think [allocate on first use] has something to do with that gsl_vector_alloc() function, but I am still not sure about point 4.

Comment: The macro just expands to regular code. If you did just `static type var = (initialization);`, you'd be missing the whole point of having a macro in the first place. Can you even have an `if` outside a function to begin with?

Comment: @MadPhysicist [#define Staticdef(type, var, initialization) \ static type var = (initialization);] that whole thing is a macro.(I know the style is weird)

Comment: (1) It doesn't have to start at zero, but the test that follows has to be able to identify the initial value so it knows it needs to initialize it, and (2) The second form won't work because a static initialization has to be constant and not contain any executable code.  If you try it, you'll get a compile-time error.

Comment: @TomKarzes thanks so much, I understand both of your point.

Comment: The macro can only be used inside a function. The `type` is expected to be a pointer type. The `var = 0` in the macro should really be `var = NULL` to let you know that `var` needs to be a pointer. The first time the function is called, the `if` statement will  be true (i.e. `var == NULL`), and the `initialization` function will be called. Which means that whatever text is substituted for `initialization` (e.g. `gel_vector_alloc(20))` must be an expression whose type is the `type` passed to the macro. Note the macro doesn't do any error checking to see if the `initialization` actually worked.

Answer (score 1):

The static local variables are initializes only ones and retain their value between the calls.

But the idea of this code is extremely bad. It can be considered only for the pointer types.

Why. Because it hard to make zero an illegal value for the integer types.

Generally speaking IMO using this macro in this code is pointless and only makes code harder to read and more error prone

Comment: Yes this doesn’t “solve” the problem, just obscures it.

Comment: Also, it is an invitation for trouble the day the code is used in the presence of threads.